# How to retrieve SQL Server database roles for an Active Directory domain group

Tags: sql-server, database, dns, role, active-directory-group

I have the following environment:

- Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 64bit version 11.0.5623.0 running on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
- I have a domain called **MyDomain**, all end users are member of this domain, e.g. user **Donald** from the USA and user **Fritz** from Germany
- For each country I have a dedicated domain group e.g. **MyDomain_Sales_USA** group contains the US user Donald, **MyDomain_Sales_GER** contains the German user Fritz
- I have one SQL Server instance in the `MyDomain` with a `Sales` database.
- The `Sales` database contains a table called `Products` that is shown here:

  [image]
- End users access the `Products` table with their domain account (single sign on) to read data

The business case:

- USA users that are members of the domain group **MyDomain_Sales_USA** only see the products with `Country = USA`, similarly German users only see the Germany products.
- users are added and removed from the two domain groups frequently
- The SQL Server admins only want to configure the domain groups. No domain users are configured in the SQL Server.

My approach:

1. Using SQL Server Management Studio I added the domain groups **MyDomain_Sales_USA** and **MyDomain_Sales_GER** to the SQL Server Security\Logins node and mapped each group to the Sales database.
2. I created two database roles in the `Sales` database, `SalesRole_USA` and `SalesRole_GER`. Using the database role properties dialog I added the `MyDomain_Sales_USA` as a member to the `SalesRole_USA` role and the `MyDomain_Sales_GER` to the `SalesRole_GER` role
3. I created a view in products database with the following select statement

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Products 
   WHERE Country = GetCurrentUserCountry()
   ```

Here's my question:

How can I in the `GetCurrentUserCountry()` function to determine to which database role the connected user belongs?

In other words: if Donald executes the select statement above then the function must return 'USA', if Fritz executes the statement then the function must return 'GER'

My expectation is the following:

1. SQL Server grants access to Donald and Fritz because their domain groups are registered and mapped to the `Sales` database
2. So it must be possible to retrieve the database roles for the connected user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GetCurrentUserCountry() function I used the system function IS_MEMBER('MyDomain_Sales_USA') and IS_MEMBER('MyDomain_Sales_GER'), this works fine but has a small disadvantage cause I have to update the function everytime a new country group is created.